# When using React Navigation, opening the app with notifications causes the headers to grow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

Using React-Native 0.59.8
NativeBase 2.13.7
react-navigation 3.11.1
android 9

When open an app by clicking on it
[image]

when open an app by notification
[image]

In addition, the statusBar changes color.
I can't guess the cause of this problem.

Below is the code of the screenshot.

```
import ExtraDimensions from 'react-native-extra-dimensions-android';
import {
  Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Text, View, Content,
} from 'native-base';

const headerHeight = ExtraDimensions.getStatusBarHeight() + 40;

<Container style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.GRAY_LV0 }}>
  <Header
    transparent
    style={{
      height: headerHeight,
      borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
      borderBottomColor: Colors.GRAY_LV4,
    }}
  >
    <Left style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        transparent
        onPress={close}
      >
        <Image
          style={{ height: 25, width: 25, tintColor: Colors.GRAY_LV7 }}
          source={{ uri: images.back }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Left>
    <Body style={{ flex: 3, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 22, width: 22, tintColor: Colors.GRAY_LV4, marginRight: 5,
        }}
        source={{ uri: images.settingLight }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>
        설정
      </Text>
    </Body>
    <Right style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} />
  </Header>
</Container>





const MyStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Setting:SettingContainer,
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Comment: looks like it is due to `style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.GRAY_LV0 }}.`

Comment: @ChotalaParesh 
Not only the color, but the height is completely different.